# How to rename excel sheet name dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

I have created an excel workbook with many sheets like sheet1, sheet2,... etc. How can I rename these tab names dynamically in C#?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't spedify how do you  access the excel file. However, example from [here](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=74551) might be useful for you if you're using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. Note that it opens first sheet in the file, line: `(Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1)`

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Excel.ApplicationClass xl=new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        Excel.Workbook xlBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlSheet;
        string laPath = Server.MapPath(@"\excel\xl_table.xls");
        xlBook = (Workbook)xl.Workbooks.Open(laPath,oMissing,
          oMissing,oMissing,oMissing ,oMissing,oMissing,oMissing
         ,oMissing,oMissing,oMissing,oMissing,oMissi ng,oMissing,oMissing);
        xlSheet = (Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlSheet.Name = "CIAO";
        xlBook.Save();
        xl.Application.Workbooks.Close();
```

Comment: yeah...super cool...what about other sheets?2nd and 3rd sheet so on?

Comment: @Sisya, To rename all sheets wrap these 2 lines i an loop:             `for (int i = 1; i < xlBook.Worksheets.Count; i++)
            {
                xlSheet = (Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets.get_Item(i);
                xlSheet.Name = "CIAO"+i;
            }`

Comment: You should use `Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();` instead of `Excel.ApplicationClass xl = new Excel.ApplicationClass();` to avoid the compilation error "Interop type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead." Other than that works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

One short note: 
If you don't need to specify them, you can get rid of all these optional parameters and use the short form:

```
xlBook = (Workbook)xl.Workbooks.Open(laPath);
```

Regards,
Jörg