# Programmatically change the sheet name of a Excel File

Tags: c#, vb.net

Whats the easiest way to change a sheet name of a newly create .xls file using VB.net.

The .xls is created as follows in a directory location:

```
filename = strDirectoryName & "\1-TestFeedFile-" & strToday & "-" & iFile.ToString() & "of" & totalFile.ToString() & ".xls"

outputWriter = File.CreateText(filename)
```

The header of the xls file is created as follows:

```
 line = "Blah1" & Chr(9) & "Blah2" & Chr(9) & "Blah3" & Chr(9)

outputWriter.WriteLine(line)
```

This code was orginally written to create a .txt file but was changed to a create a .xls, in that case I'm wondering if i'll have to change the code to create an new excel object which then can be used and access its sheet property?

I don't mind if the solution is in VB.net or C#

Comment: A downvote with no comment? At least say why you have done this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename excel sheet name dynamically in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561012/how-to-rename-excel-sheet-name-dynamically-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the sheet name, I'd recommend using the [Interop Assemblies](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel)

also, [check out this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4561012/1178921)