# Write arrays into excel file

Tags: c#, excel

I have a list of array `List<float[]>` and I want to create excel file so i can email the arrays for testing. I need it in excel and not XML - serialization will not do here.
I want to have each array in its own worksheet(tab) - here CSV goes out of the window :(

Can someone guide me what is the best approach for achieving it? using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` seems like overkill for my needs but if this is the best way i would appreciate a sample on how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel overkill?

Comment: just because i find it hard to work with it. every small change you have hundreds on options that i never know which to choose.

Comment: Understandable, it is a massive library but absolutely worth digging into one day if you plan on doing more Excel interop. It's incredible what you can achieve. Best of luck with your project!

Comment: Seems like i must have office installed on the server - is it correct? If so is there anyway to overcome it?

Comment: Ah.. unfortunately you cannot use the Office PIA's (Primary Interop Assemblies) without Office. You'll either have to install Office on the development server or not use the PIA's approach. I'm assuming that the target computer where this list gets emailed to **will** have Excel. If that's true, you can simply email the CSV list (yes, CSV), create a macro-enabled workbook and develop some VBA code to parse the CSV list. It's still possible, don't give up. The only downside of this approach is your code will be embedded into that specific workbook.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Interop is probably the simplest thing to do.

If l is your list:

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    xlApp.Visible = true;
    xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    int nWS = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count;
    for (int i = nWS; i < l.Count; i++)
        xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    int iWS = 1;
    foreach (float[] ff in l)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[iWS++];
        int idxRow = 1;
        foreach (float aFloat in ff)
            ws.Cells[idxRow++, 1] = aFloat;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, that is what i needed. I'm not able to rename the sheets. when i'm doing var sheet = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[0].name = "abc";I'm getting an exception.

Comment: Try this for renaming the sheet: `Worksheet xlSheet = (Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); xlSheet.Name = "abc"` [**Source Reference Here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561012/how-to-rename-excel-sheet-name-dynamically-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I think this happens because the indexing for the worksheets collection is 1-based, not 0-based. If you write something like ws.Name = "abc" inside the foreach everything should work.

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli that's true, but it will still copy it as a string to the worksheet rather than a formula, right?

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can follow theses steps

1 Add Reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

2 Add using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in your class

3 try this code

Reading

```
            var applicationClass = new Application();
            var workbook = applicationClass.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing
                                , Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            var worksheet = workbook.GetWorksheet(sheet);
            var usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

            for (int i = beginIndexRow; i < usedRange.Rows.Count; i++) 
            {
                var input = (Range)usedRange.Cells[i, 1]; //I read the first column

            }
            workbook.Close(false, workbookPath, null);
            applicationClass.Quit();

            while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(usedRange) > 0)
            { }
            while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet) > 0)
            { }
            while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook) > 0)
            { }
            while (Marshal.ReleaseComObject(applicationClass) > 0)
            { }
```

Writing

```
 usedRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2 = .....; //I write the first column
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) api pretty easy to work with and way faster because it generate Excel XML instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com):

```
var list = new List<float[]>() { new float[] { 1, 2 }, new float[] { 3, 4 } };

var wb = new XLWorkbook();
int i = 1;
foreach (var l in list)
    wb.AddWorksheet("Sheet" + i++).FirstCell().Value = l;

wb.SaveAs("Arrays.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at Matt Hidinger's open source project - DoddleReport - "Out of the box it can render reports to Excel, PDF, HTML, and CSV – fully pluggable of course".

It can generate tabular reports from any IEnumerable datasource